# Minimal degree of rational curves on Fano variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Theorem**. if $X$ is a Fano variety of dimension $n > 0$, then through any point $x \in X$ there is a rational curve of $(-K_{X})$-degree at most $n + 1$.

One can find this theorem in Debarre's book, Higher-Dimensional Algebraic Geometry on page 61.

**Question**: Let $X$ be hypersurface of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$. Is it possible to improve the estimation given by theorem?

**Comment 1.** Let $X$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ of degree $d$. Canonical class equals restriction of $\mathcal{O}(-n-1+d)$. Let $C$ be a rational curve in $X$. Denote by $degC$ the degree of $C$ as a curve in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$. Theorem implies

$$degC (n+1 -d) \leq n+1$$.

$$deg C \leq \frac{n+1}{n+1-d}$$

**Comment 2.** If $d < n$ then one can prove that for every point $x$ there is a line (curve $C$ with $degC = 1$) on $X$ passing though $x$. This is the best estimation (and for some $n$ and $d$ it indeed improves estimation from theorem).

Let me sketch the proof. $X$ is defined by equation $f$. One can consider Taylor expansion of $f$ near a point $x \in X$. We can consider homogeneous parts of this expansion $f_1, \dots, f_d$. Then we consider system of equations $f_1 = \dots = f_d = 0$ on $\mathbb{P} ( T_{x} \mathbb{P}^n ) = \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. If $d<n$ then the set of solutions is not empty. Solutions of the system are lines passing through $x$.